# Keep patched kernel module over updates

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, patch

After a small modification of a kernel module (eg. adding just another USB DeviceId to a device driver), is it possible to hold back updates for this module (eg. by `apt-get upgrade`) and is there any reliable method to determine how long the module will stay compatible?

- What are the conditions for a binary module to fit into a kernel image?
- Would it be possible to have a post install hook, that keeps track of the updated module sources, patches and build it on any kernel image update, as long as the patch matches?
- How are the chances that such a patch would actually make up a working module, as long as it can be applied?

The goal is to have the machine with the modified module following package updates as long as possible, and then stay stuck on compatible versions until the developer delivers an updated patched module binary or source.

Comment: 1. When the system tries to load the module, it checks if the kernel proper and other loaded modules export the symbols needed by that module. The needed and the provided versions and checksums of these symbols are also checked (if this is enabled in the kernel). 2. As for the "hook", DKMS serves that purpose well, see Shuduo's answer below. 3. As long as the version of the kernel does not change significantly, the chances everything will work are rather high, I suppose. In our distros ([ROSA](http://www.rosalab.com/)), we handle some drivers this way.

Answer (score 1):

you may consider to use DKMS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support.

Comment: Yes, DKMS is intended to solve exactly that problem. It is already enabled in many popular Linux distros by default.